# Chrome not launching Selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, behat

I am doing some test automation with behat and I was running the selenium webdriver with chrome. But I don't know how whenever I run the java -jar server standalone, instead of opening chrome, it's opening Firefox. And my tests are not working properly as well. Can you lend me a hand?
This is my `behat.yml` file

```
default: 
autoload: 
   '': %paths.base%/Sites
gherkin:
    cache: ~
extensions:
            Behat\MinkExtension:
                    base_url: https://www.google.com
                    browser_name: 'chrome'
                    selenium2: ~
            Bex\Behat\BrowserInitialiserExtension:
                    browser_window_size: 1440x1776
            Bex\Behat\StepTimeLoggerExtension:
                    output: console
                    enabled_always: true
translation:
            locale: en
suites:
    test_site:
        paths: [ %paths.base%/features ]
        contexts: [ TestSitesContext ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue with `behat/mink-extension` version `2.3`:

https://github.com/Behat/MinkExtension/issues/309

As a workaround try to use `behat/mink-extension` version `2.2`

Comment: Thank you very much. Didn't notice that. It was too hard to figure out what was the issue. I was thinking something related with my code. Thank you very much.